# invalid object name 'dbo.EvaluationTerms'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two project folders- `Proj.Domain.Core.ClassAgg` and `Proj.Domain.Evaluation.EvaluationAgg` which contain my models classes.

My `Year` class:

```cs
namespace Proj.Domain.Core.ClassAgg
{
    public class Year
    {
        public Year()
        {
            EvaluationTerms = new List<EvaluationTerm>();
        }
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public int ClassGroupId { get; set; }
        public int AcademicYearId { get; set; }
        public int NumDivisions { get; set; }
        public int PlannedStrength { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<EvaluationTerm> EvaluationTerms { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

My `EvaluationTerm` class in different project:

```
namespace Proj.Domain.Evaluation.EvaluationAgg
{
    public class EvaluationTerm
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public int YearId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Proj.Domain.Core.ClassAgg` has reference to `Proj.Domain.Evaluation.EvaluationAgg`.

I am trying to access `ClassYear` collection from service class in `Proj.Domain.Evaluation.EvaluationAgg`.

```
namespace Proj.Application.Core.ClassSvc
{
    public class YearService : IYearService
    {
        private readonly IYearRepository _yearRepository;

        public YearService(IClassYearRepository yearRepository)
        {
            _yearRepository = yearRepository;
        }
        public List<Year> GetYears()
        {
            return _yearRepository.GetAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Even if I reference `Year` namespace in Application project, I am not able to retrieve `EvaluationTerm` data as it is in different project.

Error:
In  collection.

> invalid object name 'dbo.EvaluationTerms'.

Comment: The exception suggests that the class is known to the EF model, but doesn't have a table in the database.

Comment: The table is already present. As the db set is defined in 2 different namespace, it is not able to find dbo.EvaluationTerms in Proj.Application.Core.ClassSvc. that's why it throws error- 'invalid object name'. Can anyone help me to solve this.- (1) to relate dbsets from two different projects. or (2) to make Proj.Application.Core dbsets as common or accessible to other projects.

Comment: Just to be specific about the question- I am updating it. I have different UnitOfWork defined for different projects(Evaluation,Core,Inventory,etc.). How can I make UnitOfWork of Core project available across other projects because I am putting the frequently used dbsets in Core project.